# How to compute correlation for pandas dataframe created using for loop

Tags: python

I have created a dataframe in pandas, using a For loop. I am unable to compute the correlations for the same. My for loop is like this:

```
for i in range(5):
    df=web.DataReader(tickers[i], 'yahoo', startDate, endDate)['Adj Close']
    monthly_df=df.resample('BM', how=lambda x: x[-1])
    rets=monthly_df.pct_change()
    rets = pd.Series(["{0:.2f}%".format(val * 100) for val in rets], index = rets.index)
    rets=rets.rename(columns={'Adj Close':'Monthly Returns'})
```

I am unable to use corr() function with rets. It keeps giving the following error:

> TypeError: corr() missing 1 required positional argument: 'other'

Comment: Your code does not seem to contain the line resulting in the error. Could you complete it?

Comment: Yes sir. The line resulting in the error is as follows: corr=rets.corr()

Comment: Despite that you seem to be confusing pandas.DataFrame.corr with pandas.Series.corr. The former computes pairwise correlation of columns and the latter computes correlation of one series with another one.

Comment: C.f. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html and http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.corr.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me your problem is that you are using pandas.Series.corr instead of pandas.DataFrame.corr. If you just want the pairwise correlation of rets columns, try the following: (append to your for loop)

```
rets = rets.to_frame()
corr = rets.corr()
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt input. I did as you suggested and appended the code. Now I get the following message when I print(corr):                  Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []

Comment: Not sure what the problem is without seeing the data. Is rets having sensible values before the to_frame()?

Comment: This is the output of print(rets):                  
Date               0
2007-05-31     nan%
2007-06-29   -1.78%
2007-07-31   -3.20%
2007-08-31    1.29%
2007-09-28    3.58%
2007-10-31    1.48%
2007-11-30   -4.40%
2007-12-31   -0.86%
2008-01-31   -6.12%
2008-02-29   -3.48%
2008-03-31   -0.60%
2008-04-30    4.75%
2008-05-30    1.07%
2008-06-30   -8.60%
2008-07-31   -0.99%
2008-08-29    1.22%
2008-09-30   -9.08%
2008-10-31  -16.94%
2008-11-28   -7.48%
2008-12-31    0.78%
2017-05-31    0.16%

[121 rows x 1 columns]

Comment: Ah, well, this is just one data column. What is the feature you are actually wanting to correlate it with?

Comment: I wish to correlate it with 4 other columns, each representing a similar time series-so 5 time series in total.

Comment: Well you want them all in the same dataframe, i.e. 121 rows x 5 columns. Then you call DataFrame.corr() on it and it should give you the pairwise correlations for all your columns.

Comment: If you only want to correlate this column with the 4 others keep rets a Series and make each one of the other 4 columns a Series, i.e. s_1, s_2, s_3, s_4, and call corr on Series rets.corr(s_1), rets.corr(s_2), rets.corr(s_3), rets.corr(s_4).

Comment: Yes sir. I want all the columns in the same dataframe (121 rows x 5 columns). How do I add all the 5 columns to the same dataframe? rets.append(rets) doesn't seem to do it. Thank you...!

Comment: Have a look at the constructor of DataFrame http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html and pass it the appropriate data.

Comment: Thank you for your kind revert. The issue is resolved :)